# Excel formula to output name in first column based on a value in the 3rd column

Tags: excel

I have a data table with 8 columns and i want to know if anyone can help me come up with a formula to get the name in the first column if i enter a value into the columns (3,4,5,6,7,8).

I want the name from the first column to appear in another table on another sheet where only names appear where data is in the columns (3,4,5,6,7 & 8)

[image]

Comment: Do you want the name in the first column to appear in a popup? (msgbox) Can you be more specific

Comment: Does the appearance of the name in column 1 depend on values entered in all the columns ie 3,4,5,6,7 & 8? Please could you add some more info to your qestion.

Comment: Please add expected output, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  =IF(OR(Sheet1!C2<>"";Sheet1!D2<>"";Sheet1!E2<>"";Sheet1!F2<>"";Sheet1!G2<>"";Sheet1!H2<>"");Sheet1!A2;"")
```

You can use C1 = 1 .... if you prefer.

And C1,D1,E1... have to be replaced with your columns.

Also Sheet1 have to replaced with your sheet name

Comment: Sorry it does work, but this is not the formula that i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Do you need the AND instead of OR?

Comment: No.. I need to populate another table to show only the names with numbers in colums (4 to 8).

Comment: Mmm I don't know if I've understood well, maybe the only thing that is miss is the Sheet name from which values are taken, try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Pivot tables.

First create a new column in the existing table:
If you only having positive values then it is:
**=sum(C2:H2)**
If you have zero and negative values as well it would be like this:
**=IF(COUNTBLANK(C2:H2)=6;0;1)**

Then make a pivot table with the "TO/TA name" in the Row Labels and the new column in Report filter - where you then removes the "0".

Comment: Thanks :) I will try this and let you know as soon as i get time to work on that.